# Issues printing out an element from my LinkedList

Tags: java

Ok, so I am trying to print out some elements from a LinkedList, and while some will print, some are throwing exceptions. I will try to be as clear as possible in my code here with multiple examples.Sorry in advance if I go overboard.

I created some objects from this constructor:

```
public Station(String city, Calendar arrival, Calendar departure, int day)
```

Example of object creation:

```
Station stop1 = new Station("Vancouver", null, getCalendar(20,30), 1);  
Station stop2 = new Station("Kamloops", getCalendar(6,00), getCalendar(6,35), 2);
Station stop3 = new Station("Jasper", getCalendar(16,00), getCalendar(17,30), 2);
```

The getCalendar you see if from this method:

```
private static Calendar getCalendar(int hour, int minute) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);         
    return c;
}
```

This enables me to set up departure and arrival times. 
Those times are stored via another class and then I have a getter to return it as a string so the time looks appropriate. That method looks like this and it's possible something is wrong here because the exception points me back here.

```
public String getDeparture(){
    String curDTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", this.departure.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),this.departure.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    return curDTime;        
}
```

So if I just try to print out the departure time from the objects I created, it works and returns the time to me.

```
System.out.println(stop1.getDeparture());
```

Shows: 20:30

Now from here I added all the stops into a LinkedList
I have a display method to print the elements of the LinkedList as follows:

```
public void displaySchedule(){
    System.out.println("Station \t Arrival \t Departure \t Day");       
    for(Station list: schedule){
        System.out.println(list.getCity());     
    }
```

The output looks like:

```
Station      Arrival     Departure   Day
Vancouver
Kamloops
Jasper
etc..
```

Now whenever I try to print the arrival and departure dates like so:

```
 for(Station list: schedule){
        System.out.println(list.getDeparture());
```

I get

```
Station      Arrival     Departure   Day
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Station.getArrival(Station.java:35)
at TrainTimeTable.displaySchedule(TrainTimeTable.java:18)
at TrainTest.main(TrainTest.java:50)
```

One thing I just noticed. When I print just the Departure list I get no times and an error as shown above but if I print just the Arrival list, the times will print but then follows with an error. 
Sorry this was so long. Any thoughts from anyone as to what I should look into?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
So after i JUST posted my question I figured something out. The first Arrival time is set to Null and the Last departure time is set to Null. That's why one list throws the exception at the beginning and the other at the end.

EDIT 2:
I added the other method for getArrival

```
public String getArrival(){
    String curATime = String.format("%02d:%02d", this.arrival.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),this.arrival.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    return curATime;        
}
```

It's clear to me now I have to set these getters up to deal with the two NULL times I am using. Thanks!

Comment: Exception is thrown from `Station.getArrival` method. Please include this method as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `null` to `getarrival` method and trying to convert it.

```
Station stop1 = new Station("Vancouver", null, getCalendar(20,30), 1);
```

here arrival is `null`.  Please check if the variable is not null before applying any transformations.

```
    public String getArrival(){
       String curATime =null;
       if(this.arrival!=null)
       {
        curATime = String.format("%02d:%02d",this.arrival.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),this.arrival.get(Calendar.MINUTE));             
        }
        return curATime ;    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! After writing this whole thing out I clued in. "It's the NULLS!!"  :)